# Saving Excel Add-In in Windows 7

Tags: vba, excel, windows-7, uac

I have an Excel add-in I am developing that works fine in Windows XP.  However, I just got a hold of Windows 7 Professional and now I cannot save this add-in, either manually from the VBA Editor or programmatically using `ThisWorkbook.Save`.

The error message says

> "Micrsosoft Office Excel cannot access the file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office 12\LIBRARY[some random 8-character string rather than the name of my add-in]".

One of this dialog error's possible explanations is that "The file name or path does not exist". Well, of course it doesn't.

I tried turning off read-only on the add-in file and its directory, as well as "Unblocking" the file (seems to be a new Windows 7 feature) using the Properties dialogs, but to no avail.

How do I get this basic save functionality to work in Windows 7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing this is the UAC behaviour of Windows that was introduced in Vista, and is still in Windows 7.

Have a look at [this Microsoft page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/What-is-User-Account-Control) for a user perspective, and [this MSDN one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756996.aspx) for an idea of how to program with it in mind.

In summary, you can't write to Program Files without asking for elevation if you have UAC on.

(Edit: couple of extra points raised by the comments)
If this is just for development, you can run Excel using right click->'Run as Administrator', which will let you save where you want, or you can save in %AppData%\Microsoft\Addins, which is also a trusted location (see [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140968(office.10).aspx) for more details of that).

Comment: I think you're correct about the UAC.  I checked out the links, but didn't find anything that helps me around this problem.  My add-in file is actually located in a Trusted Location used by Excel, not the Program Files directory.  I have to believe that there are other add-ins written in VBA that have encountered this problem...

Comment: Are you able to save inside the user folder (%appdata%)? If your Trusted Location is not in Program Files, but still in one of the restricted places you'll still have problems. If this is just for development, you can run Excel using right click->'Run as Administrator', which will let you save where you want.

Comment: Ant, you're right on the money.  The add-in must be saved to C:\Users\\[User Name]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Addins, or you can use a Trusted Location path if logged in under a UAC.  Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related with the directory you try to save the file. Thus, one possible solution is to use an alternative directory. In order to do that,
- First, remove any previous reference.
- Next, you need to create a trusted folder location (File/Options/Trust Center/Trust Center Settings/Trusted Locations/Add new location).
- Copy the addins to this newly created trusted folder.
- Finally, File/Options/Add-ins/Manage Excel Add-ins, add the addin.